# Capture primary image color

Tags: c#, .net, image, graphics, bitmap

For example - I have many photos with grass or forest and they are simply "green".

Photo with sea and sky is blue, photo with snow is white.

I need something ( idea / algorithm ) to solve my problem but dont know how to make it fast and easy. (I prefer c# but java is good too).

Comment: You might want to go into more detail on how you decide which color to get.  Right now it's unclear what a picture with both sky and grass would be.

Comment: What about a photo with 50% sky and 50% snow? What would you class that as?

Comment: I think you may want to research [image histograms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_histogram) for color/tonal distribution maps.

Comment: I don't know excalty if it's possible, i just want to get "general" color, something like that - On this image i can see sky and snow I can  say that my "looking for color" of this image is brightblue

Comment: Surprisingly similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146994/how-to-reset-value-of-captured-pixel

Comment: I think JYelton is close to solve, histograms is good point to start. I haven't wrote that i'll work only with images that are quite "one color" (no images with hmm for example rainbow or other thing with lot of colors)

Comment: Marc-André Jutras - sum of every pixels isn't bad but i'm worry that it can be quite slow (even when get pixels with locking bitmap) i think it can be faster when use histograms or something else?

Comment: Ok i've solved my problem - just scale image to 1 x 1 pixel and that pixel has color which i'm looking for, thanks